# Problema con lectura de directorio is_dir()

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo el siguiente código, y me da error:  ErrorException (E_ERROR)
is_dir() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given

```
<?php
$dir = dir(public_path('/images/events/'.$code));

if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "nombre archivo: $file : tipo archivo: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

Sí a la variable $dir le paso la ruta de la siguiente forma, funciona:

```
$dir = '/images/events/'.$event->code
```

Con la siguiente forma:

```
$dir = dir(public_path('/images/events/'.$code));
```

Imprimo lo que devuelve, y es lo siguiente (parece un objeto):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: Es necesario que esté de la siguinete manera: $dir = dir(public_path('/images/events/'.$code));

Código final:

```
if ($dir) {

      while (($archivo = $dir->read()) !== false) {


          $zip->addFile($dir . $archivo, $dir . $archivo);

      }
  }
```

Me da el siguiente error:  ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Object of class Directory could not be converted to string

Me Entiendo que dice que el objeto de la clase directorio no puede ser convertido a cadena... Creo que sigo con el mismo problema pero ahora en este condicional:  `$zip->addFile($dir . $archivo, $dir . $archivo);`

Será en `$dir . $archivo` y nosé como solventarlo.

Comment: si `$code` es un objeto y lo que completa el path está en `$event->code` no creo que haya otra forma salvo usar  `$otrocode = $event->code; $dir = dir(public_path('/images/events/'.$otrocode));`

Answer (score 0):

`dir()` devuelve una instancia de la clase Directory. Las funciones que usas para leer el directorio no son necesarias. Si necesitas usar `dir()` prueba con esto:

```
<?php
$dir = dir(public_path('/images/events/'.$code));

if ($dir) { // dir() devuelve null o false en caso de error
    // No es necesario opendir(), el directorio ya está abierto

    // Y ahora usamos el método Directory::read() en vez de readdir()
    while (($file = $dir->read()) !== false) {
        echo "nombre archivo: $file : tipo archivo: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
    }

    $dir->close(); // Cambiamos closedir() por el método de la clase
}
?>
```

Échale un vistado a la función [dir()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.dir.php) y a la clase [Directory](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.directory.php).

Comment: Gracias @joas ahora tengo otra duda, la puse al final de la pregunta (La actualicé) y está en "Código final" a ver si puedes ayudarme con eso también. Muchas gracias!